# jquery data attribute with input selector in a loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an html table built from a database query which loops through and creates a button for each camera name found and puts them in a table:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{

?>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" data-hash="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>">
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

This resolves to something like this:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" data-hash="0d3d0ac6e54a640c73f1149d4d0bbc38e99d10f5" value="Office Window">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" data-hash="b824cba374c3d5ab7806ad8260c939323c03147b" value="aaa">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" data-hash="ec9658f0c1855e2e2ac09ae284f5e6990dbf445d" value="laptop">
</td>
</tr>
```

Notice the data hash attribute is different for each button. I want to process this button with my jquery code:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    var camerahash = $('input').data('hash');
    console.log($('input').data('hash'));
});
```

No matter which button I click I will always get the hash from the first button I click: `0d3d0ac6e54a640c73f1149d4d0bbc38e99d10f5`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have several .play buttons you need to dtermine what kind of play was cliked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input').data('hash')` gives you the data attribute of the first input in the selection use `$(this).data('hash')` to get the data attribute of the currently clicked input

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify which input element to read.
Try something like:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var camerahash = $this.data('hash');
    console.log($this.data('hash'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always calling the first object of .play. This would be a correct way:

```
$('.play').on('click', function(){

  var camerahash = $(this).data('hash');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always grab them by using the `.attr(data-hash)` html5 attribute.

Try:

```
$('.play').on('click', function() {
      var _hash = $(this).attr('data-hash');
      console.log(_hash);
});
```

Comment: The [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (note: OP is using the one I linked to, not the one you linked to) does retrieve `data-` attributes. Though its attempts to convert the value to what it thinks the appropriate datatype should be can catch people out.

Comment: Very true! i'll change that. Both are good to use, for simple strings I use data-attr, but .data() is good for complex stuff.

Comment: To retrieve attributes I prefer to use `.attr('data-...` rather than `.data(...`, just as you've shown, and do my own type conversion as appropriate. I use `.data()` only to retrieve values I've previously stored with `.data()`. Just my personal preference. (So I wasn't objecting to your use of `.attr()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will return the first one that it comes to. Use this instead

```
<script>
    $("input.play").click(function() {
        alert($(this).data('hash'));
    });
</script>
```